# inapp purchase call failetransaction when return...?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

In my iPhone app, I implemented inAppPurchase, so user can purchase products in app. It's live on itunes app store.
I tested it well with sandbox where any credit card verification page was not displayed.
On live when user try to buy something it goes on app store from my app to approve his/her information.

[image]

When user pass all process, and open my app again from background.

[image]

Above msg prompt to user which I wrote in my **failedTransaction** in **-(void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions** method.
This method is below:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
{
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone guide me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your server where verification part is implemented.

Check following things:

```
{
    "status" : 0,
    "receipt" : { (receipt here) },
    "latest_receipt" : "(base-64 encoded receipt here)",
    "latest_receipt_info" : { (latest receipt info here) }
}
```

Check these things first at your server side and also debugging the code and let me know.

One of the above response might be creating problem.

Thanks,

Hemang.

Comment: Hello Hemang, thanks for reply. But actually when it come back to my app after credit card verification, at that time if completeTransaction call,only then I got receipt but it goes in failedTransaction.

Comment: Add this method:  case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                
    break;
Add this method also. And then check it. And if still you'll get failed transaction then something is wrong with server side verification.

Comment: ok, ok so I'm missing stareRestored method in my updateTransaction part. Is that thing create problems. Is it like when it come back from credit card verification, it call this method.

Comment: Yes. It might be possible. Because in subscription, mostly Restored method is called and in Restored method, you need to implement finish transaction code. Add this method and test it

Comment: but how can I test it, because as I post in my question. In sandbox account it not go anywhere for credit card verification so it go really smooth with my above mentioned code for **updatedTransactions**. This issue with live app, when it go to credit card verification and user have to open my app again, when he verified with it.

Comment: I want to know one thing: Where are you calling this method?     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self]; If this method is in your viewWillDisappear or somewhere where your app is going in background and this method is called then it may be one of the reason.

Comment: hello Hemang, please can you guide me properly. I stuck here from last many weeks and no issue found in sandbox. but my live app not working with the same thing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22572/discussion-between-deer-and-hemang)